# How to create non-duplicate lines between all selected points in Spatialite?

Tags: sql, spatialite

There is a [nice answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/58543/5666) for the similar question for PostGIS.

I tried to adapt it for my case where I need to connect all points from a point layer, but unfortunately I get duplicate geometries: lines from *point n* to *point m* and from *point m* to *point n*. Here is the query I use. `check_points` is the point layer and `cp_path` is the layer where I want to store created lines.

```
WITH points1 AS (SELECT geometry FROM check_points),
     points2 AS (SELECT geometry FROM check_points)
INSERT INTO cp_path (geometry) 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MakeLine(points1.geometry, points2.geometry)
               FROM points1, points2
               WHERE points1.geometry != points2.geometry)
```

How can I avoid duplicated geometries?

Comment: I would check AND rowid.points1<rowid.points2. That would also make your geometry comparison unnecessary.

Comment: @user30184, it is `points1.rowid` I guess. Are you sure this should work? I tried your advise and I got an empty result.

Comment: I did not test but yes, it works after selecting also the rowid columns with this unpolished query `WITH points1 AS (SELECT rowid,geometry FROM points),
 points2 AS (SELECT rowid,geometry FROM points) INSERT INTO cp_path (geometry) SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MakeLine(points1.geometry, points2.geometry)
 FROM points1, points2 WHERE points1.geometry != points2.geometry AND points1.rowid<points2.rowid)`

Comment: @user30184, ok that one worked, thank you. Consider posting this as an answer with a bit more in detail explanation what happens when this condition is added to the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reminds the old quiz: 5 person will shake hands with each other. How many handshakes will there be in total? Is it 20 because everybody must shake hands with 4 other person? No, because if Mike shakes hands with John, John does not need to shake hands with Mike for another time.

Let's assume that you have 5 points. Point number 1 does not shake hands with herself, but only with points 2, 3, 4, and 5. When point number 2 is in turn, she quits number 1 and herself and shakes hands only with 3, 4, and 5.

With your data the handshake query becomes as:

```
WITH points1 AS (SELECT rowid,geometry FROM check_points),
     points2 AS (SELECT rowid,geometry FROM check_points) 
INSERT INTO cp_path (geometry) 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT MakeLine(points1.geometry, points2.geometry)
FROM points1, points2 
WHERE points1.rowid<points2.rowid);
```